# Is this proper Schema.org/Microdata markup for a building?

Tags: html, markup, schema.org, microdata

I am trying to add Microdata notation (using Schema.org) to my website which basically talks about buildings. I’ve been reading a lot about it but I’m still having trouble figuring out where to use `itemscope`, `itemtype` and `itemprop`.

Can anybody tell me if this is good Microdata/Schema.org markup or if I’m missing something?

```html
<div class="infobox infobox_building" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LandmarksOrHistoricalBuildings">

    <!-- Building Name -->
    <h1 class="page_title">Puente Golden Horn Metro</h1>

    <!-- Architect -->
    <div class="data_row architect" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/creator">
        <div class="tag cell">Arquitecto</div>
        <div class="value cell">
            <a href="https://stage.wikiarquitectura.com/arquitecto/virlogeux-michel/" itemprop="Person">Michel Virlogeux</a>
            <a href="https://stage.wikiarquitectura.com/arquitecto/kiran-hakan/" itemprop="Person">Hakan Kıran</a>                                                  
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Height -->
    <div class="data_row" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/height">
        <div class="tag cell">Altura</div>
        <div class="value cell" itemprop="QuantitativeValue">65m</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Width -->
    <div class="data_row" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/width">
        <div class="tag cell">Ancho</div>
        <div class="value cell" itemprop="QuantitativeValue">12,6m</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Location -->
    <div class="data_row" itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <div class="tag cell">Ubicación</div>
        <div class="value cell" itemprop="streetAddress">Arap Cami Mahallesi, Beyoğlu/İstanbul, Turquía</div>
    </div>

</div> <!-- infobox -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to confuse properties and types.

In Microdata, properties get specified in the `itemprop` attribute, while types get specified in the `itemtype` attribute.

If you only use the vocabulary Schema.org, you’ll use the full URI for types (`itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress"`), while you use just the slug for properties (`itemprop="address"`).

In Schema.org, it’s easy to see what is what, because they follow [the convention](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/96970/17633) that the first letter of properties is lowercase (`address`), and the first letter of types is uppercase (`PostalAddress`).

---

Syntactically, you are doing it correctly with `address`+`PostalAddress`, but wrong with `creator`+`Person` and `height`/`width`+`QuantitativeValue`.

That said, you are also making some vocabulary errors. The `LandmarksOrHistoricalBuildings` type can’t have a `creator` nor a `height` nor a `width` property in the first place.

You can see which properties a type can have by visiting the type’s page ([`LandmarksOrHistoricalBuildings`](http://schema.org/LandmarksOrHistoricalBuildings)) and checking the first table.

Comment: Hi @unor , thanks for your feedback, the capital versus lower case distinction does help. So in your opinion is LandmarksOrHistoricalBuildings the correct property for a building (such as the Empire State for instance) or is there a better one? Or can I remove the property type altogether at the level that I currently have LandmarksOrHistoricalBuildings and keep the width, height, creator properties, which in my opinion make a lot of sense for an article like this?

Comment: I've been taking a closer look at my markup after reading your comments. Would this be correct for height then?

                <!-- Height -->
  <div class="data_row" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
   <div class="tag cell">Altura</div>
   <div class="value cell" itemprop="height">65m</div>
  </div>

Comment: I tried a new approach. I've updated my questions. Do you think this new approach is any better? Could it be improved?

Comment: @GuillermoCarone: `LandmarksOrHistoricalBuildings` might be a suitable type in this case. If you don’t use a property (so the items stand on their own), they are not connected, so it would just be "a" height of anything.

Comment: @GuillermoCarone: Please don’t change your question like that (updating it with missing/unclear things is fine, but not adding something totally new). I’ll rollback your edit. If your markup works and you need a review, you can head to [codereview.se]. If you have a specific question how to use something, you can ask a new question here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem or question like you. Because my buildings are not even historical (when is a building historical?), I created my [own schema](https://www.surrounding.ch/contexts/building.jsonld):

```
{
   "@context":
   {
      "Place": "http://schema.org/Place",
      "name": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/title",
      "alternateName":"http://purl.org/dc/terms/title",
      "description": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/description",
      "geo": "http://schema.org/geo",
      "image":
      {
        "@id": "http://schema.org/image",
        "@type": "@id"
      },
      "latitude":
      {
        "@id": "http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#lat",
        "@type": "xsd:decimal"
      },
      "longitude":
      {
        "@id": "http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long",
        "@type": "xsd:decimal"
      },


      "containedInPlace":"http://schema.org/Place",
      "containsPlace":"http://schema.org/Place",
      "architect":"http://schema.org/Creator",
      "Address": "http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#Address",
      "address": "http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#address",
      "street": "http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#street-address",      
      "locality": "http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#locality",
      "region": "http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#region",
      "country": "http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#country",
      "postalCode": "http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#postal-code",

      "meter": "http://purl.org/measurement#meter",
      "kilometer": "http://purl.org/measurement#kilometer",
      "feet": "http://purl.org/measurement#feet",
      "miles": "http://purl.org/measurement#miles",

      "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
   }
}
```

But I am not sure whether google or some other search services will get the idea. If you have any improvements or ideas to the schema let me know!