# "birthPlace" expects "Place", but I don’t have a full address

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I have a database of people who provide mobile notary services. I decided to go with `Service` instead of just a `Person`, because the person provides the service.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
    <meta itemprop="serviceType" content="Notary" />
    <span itemprop="provider" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/person">
        <span itemprop="name">Derrick Calhoun</span>
        <img itemprop="image" src="/headshots/hs-3246356.jpg" alt="" />
        <span itemprop="birthPlace">Omaha, NE</span>
    </span>
    <span itemprop="telephone">555-555-5555</span>
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4" />
    Last time available:<time datetime="2015-05-08T19:30">May 8, 7:30pm</time>
    Current Location: <span itemprop="place">Lincoln, NE</span>
</div>
```

Should the `birthPlace` be formatted differently?

http://schema.org/birthPlace says that the value expected is a `Place`. However, [`Place`](http://schema.org/Place) only shows examples of places with full addresses. I only have a city.

I thought about using [`addressLocality`](http://schema.org/addressLocality), however, that is supposed to be used on a `PostalAddress`, which I do not have.

Should I embed `Place` under `provider` like this?

```
<span itemprop="provider" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/person">
    <span itemprop="name">Derrick Calhoun</span>
    <img itemprop="image" src="/headshots/hs-3246356.jpg" alt="" />
    <span itemprop="place" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/place">
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">Seattle</span>
        <span itemprop="addressRegion">WA</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

I think I am confused on the basic structure, parent child. Can anyone shed some epic light on this?

Comment: In some cases you were using `“` insteaf of `"`, which is invalid. I fixed it in the snippets.

Comment: This question is not on topic as defined in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't understand why, please ask on [meta] for help.

Comment: @Willl: I don’t see why this should be off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`birthPlace`](http://schema.org/birthPlace) property does expect a `Place` value, but `Place` doesn’t need to have a full address. You can provide as much properties of `Place` as you have/want, and the same goes for the `PostalAddress` value of its [`address`](http://schema.org/address) property (where you could provide a [`addressLocality`](http://schema.org/addressLocality) property etc.).

If you only have a city, you could use a [`City`](http://schema.org/City) value, which is a sub-type of `Place` (those are listed under "More specific Types"):

```html
<span itemprop="birthPlace" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/City">
  <span itemprop="name">Omaha</span>
</span>
```

---

Note that you are making some errors in your Schema.org use:

Schema.org terms are case-sensitive, so `person` is not the same as `Person`.  (Schema.org [follows the convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45362701/1591669) of starting properties with a lowercase letter, and types with an uppercase letter.)

- There is no `place` property, so `itemprop="place"` can’t be right.
- `itemtype="http://schema.org/place"` has to be
  `itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"`
- `itemtype="http://schema.org/person"` has to be
  `itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"`

Comment: Your example doesn‘t match your description "The birthPlace property does expect a Place value". Also I think your nesting of itemscope and itemprop isn‘t quite correct? I’d expect it should be like this: `<span itemprop="birthPlace" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
  <span itemprop="addressLocality">Omaha</span>
</span></span>`

Comment: @OopsD'oh: `City` is a sub-type of `Place`. This means that a `City` is also a `Place`. So whenever Schema.org specifies an expected value, all of its sub-types are expected, too. -- Both of our examples seem to be fine syntax-wise, they just represent the data in different ways (my example provides the name of a city; your example provides the locality of an address of a place).